# Can't active Sysprepped Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

We recently began testing Windows 10 sysprep installations and are havin an issue where we cannot change the product keys. The initial machine that was used for creating the image could activate, but all subsequent machines built with this image suffer from the same error. No product key was entered in the unattend.xml file. The initial image used was Windows 10 version 1511, which allows for Windows 7 keys to be used for activation.

When attempting the activate, the follow screen appears. In  Windows 7, you simply click on the 'Change Product Key' button and enter a valid key and everything works. In Windows 10, clicking on the button has zero effect. No window appears, and no errors either. Clicking on the 'Activate' button attempts to activate the PC, but the error message never changes.

[image]

Comment: So have you tried and used the command prompt to try and change it?  Windows 7 license can only be used, if the machine had Windows 10 previously activated on it, its simply a way from having to skip install Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 Build 10240 in the future.  Furthermore the digital entitlement is unique to a given machine, so you creating the system image after it was activated, that is likely part of the problem.

Comment: I think I just going to try and respin the image and see what happens. The PCs this is being deployed on were all previously activated with Windows 7, and we are doing clean installs, not upgrades.

Comment: That is the problem then.  You cannot go straight from Windows 7 to Windows 10 even though you can use Windows 7 license.  Your digital entitlement is clearly not being generated.  Do use the command line to try and set a license key, just to see if it works, before you go to the effort of doing the image agian.

Comment: I assume that screenshot is from `Click Start > Settings (press Windows key + i) > Update & security > Activation` correct?  I forget if you can still do "Properties" on My PC in Windows 10 or not.  the command in an elevated command prompt you want is `slui 3`

Comment: Hmm, I can access the product key by using `slui 3`, however I am then informed that that key cannot be used. The strange thing is I have activated a different machine, with the same type of key (Refurb key). I also noticed initially runnin `slmgr.exe -dli` showed the machine had a key installed. Apparently `ReArm=1` was set in the unattended.xml file, which is never good in production. Still trying to solve.

Comment: change the key via command prompt: **slmgr.vbs -ipk KEY**